# Cursor indexoutofbound error while query of a column

Tags: android, sql

I am getting index out of bound error while querying the data from SQL. Here is the code. Actually what I did that I saved the pin from the edittext to the database and now comparing the enter pin and database entry for login purpose.

```
public class LoginSCreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText enterpin;
    Button login;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    PinHelper dbhelper;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_screen);

        enterpin= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterpin);
        login= (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        dbhelper= new PinHelper(this);
        db= dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();

        final  String pin=enterpin.getText().toString();
        int pins= cursor.getColumnIndex(PinContract.NoteEntry.COLUMN_password);
        final String pwd= cursor.getString(pins);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(pin==getSinlgeEntry(pwd)){
                    Intent in= new Intent(LoginSCreen.this, CatalogActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                }else
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Pin is Incorrect", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public String getSinlgeEntry(String passWord)
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query("LOGIN", null, " PASSWORD=?", new String[]{passWord}, null, null, null);

        if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
        {
            cursor.close();
            return "NOT EXIST";
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));
        cursor.close();
        return password;
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.amitkhatkar.privatenotes, PID: 9780
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amitkhatkar.privatenotes/com.amitkhatkar.privatenotes.LoginSCreen}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)  > at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
>
> at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
>   at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)  > at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>                                                                                   at com.amitkhatkar.privatenotes.LoginSCreen.onCreate(LoginSCreen.java:40)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: are you using `getSingleEntry` method anywhere ?

Comment: yes in the line if(pin==getSingleEntry(pwd))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396604/how-to-solve-cursorindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: mike thats not working for me

Comment: It's the same problem, and the solution would be the same. If you want a specific solution, then you need to post the actual, exact code you're running. The code you've posted would be throwing a `NullPointerException` upon starting that `Activity`, not a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: its the full error code and not giving NullPointerException

Comment: Then you're not running the code you think you are. `cursor` is null when `onCreate()` runs. As soon as it hits `int pins= cursor.getColumnIndex(...);`, it would throw an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Following lines of your code

```
int pins= cursor.getColumnIndex(PinContract.NoteEntry.COLUMN_password);
final String pwd= cursor.getString(pins);
```

will give you error as your cursor is initialized in `getSingleEntry()` method. So your cursor will probably be null by this time.

Moreover you are not even using these strings anywhere.

Comment: is your table created properly?

Comment: Table is created properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
 if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
```

The cursor starting index is 0 so your null check fails. 
Use:

```
if(cursor.getCount >0)
//Your logic here
else
// UserName Not Exist
```